# Retrieving an inline CSS style value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` that is styled automatically by a template based on variable results pulled from another data source. The style value is set inline, like this:

```
<div class="view-empty message" style="display: block;">
    There are no active Invoices to display.
</div>
```

I've been able to see this in the DOM and toggle visibility back and forth, but so far have been unable to use Jquery to retrieve the style value. What I want to do is search for the div based on the class (since the "view-empty message" class is unique) and return the value of the style attribute. So in this case I would like to return either `"display: block"` or `"block"`. I've tried many different methods (such as .attr() and css. that I've seen around online ) and so far none have returned what I'm looking for. This is the latest one I'm using:

```
var displayValue = document.getElementsByClassName($(".view-empty message"))[0].style;
```

Any ideas? I appreciate the help.

Comment: Just a style tip, you'll rarely need to mix raw javascript accessors (`getElementById`, `getElementsByClassName`) etc. with jQuery. That's the beauty of jQuery :]. I'm glad you stopped and reached out once you got to that point!

Answer (score 2):

Oh sh*t. Lightbulb. Your selector is wrong. Change:

```
$('.view-empty message').attr('style');
```

to

```
$('.view-empty.message').attr('style');
```

In your selector you're trying to get `.view-empty message` which looks for an HTML element named message inside of a container with a class of `.view-empty`. Instead, you need to specify a selector for an element that has TWO CLASSES `$('.view-empty.message');`

;]

---

### -- Helpful but irrelevant now... --

You need to specify which attribute you are attempting to get the value for. Notice how I'm specifying the `'style'` attribute in the `.attr()` method. This will retrieve the value of that attribute.

```
$('.view-empty.message').attr('style');
```

Per the documentation for the `.attr()` method, there isn't actually a method that takes no parameters. http://api.jquery.com/attr/.

When you invoke the method with one value, it returns the value of the attribute.

```
<div class='foo'></div>

$('.foo').attr('class'); // returns "foo"
```

When you invoke the method with two values, it sets an attribute on the element with the name of the first argument and a value equal to the second argument.

```
<div class='foo'></div>

$('.foo').attr('style', 'display: none;');

<div class='foo' style='display: none;'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to post this! When I use this method it returns blank - just an opening and closing quote "" . Also, the method I posted that I'm using earlier returns a style object....in it all the properties are listed, but they are blank.

Comment: Oh wow, this one got me there for a minute as well. I've figured out your problem and just edited my response. See my update!

Comment: Thanks! I'm definitely grabbing the right div with this updated code (I stepped through and looked - I can see the text now) so that is a step forward. The style property still isn't being returned though....maybe there is something funky going on with they way they are styling it in this template.

Comment: do you get anything when you try `$('.view-empty.message').attr('class');` ?

Comment: also, is your style attribute being set dynamically (by some other javascript) or is it being set statically (hard-coded into the HTML)?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps try `$(".view-empty message").css('display')`?
you can also set the display property with `$(".view-empty message").css('display', 'none').`

I assume you are not using the `style='display:none'` as a flag/state variable of some sort. if you are, maybe try putting the display property in a class and use jquery's `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()`?